# Converting a NPN Circuit to PNP

Tags: relay, npn, pnp, trigger

I've got an exact circuit diagram of the circuit in NPN, but I need to convert it to PNP. Could someone help, please?

I've got a 2N2907 with me right now and I want to make my High Level trigger into Low Level trigger. However all I have got is a low level to high level trigger circuit diagram.

The Relay Module I'm using is a Delay Timer Relay with LED Display for configurations and this comes with just High Level Trigger System. Hence I need a conversion of the Low Level Signal of mine from my sensor to be detected as High by the relay module.

The Module is 
[https://www.amazon.com/Docooler-Display-Automation-Digital-Control/dp/B07L968JKC/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=docooler+delay+timer+relay&qid=1590526628&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L968JKC)

And the sensor is
 [https://www.amazon.com/E18-D80NK-Adjustable-detection-infrared-obstacles/dp/B085MHHLMD/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=e18-d80nk&qid=1590526689&sprefix=e18&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085MHHLMD)

[image: schematic]

Comment: are you already using the both the NO and NC pins of the relay?

Comment: Yes! Those are for controlling a 12V DC Motor

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the "low level trigger relay module"?  Are you trying to OR two trigger inputs together, or is the "high level trigger" the only signal you need to worry about?

Comment: Basically it's a Relay Module Board which is triggering with the High Level Trigger while I've got a NPN Sensor which gives a Low Level Trigger as a detection signal! And now I'm unable to understand what should I do except attaching another relay board to the circuit which makes it difficult for accomodation in the junction box!

Comment: @ShivanshTrivedi - You said: "*I want to make my High Level trigger into Low Level trigger*" In that case, why not use a "low level trigger" input directly? Many of the cheap relay modules sold on eBay, Amazon etc. have a "low level trigger" input, and your schematic seems to show that. So why do you need *any* external components? Please edit the question & add details explaining why you are trying to do (don't use these comments) and explain the signals you are using. Do not mention NPN or PNP again, we want to know *what you are trying* to do, NOT *how you think you should do it*. Thanks.

Comment: @ShivanshTrivedi - "*The Relay Module I'm using [...] comes with just High Level Trigger System*" So *your* relay module is NOT the same as the one in your schematic (!) as your relay module only has a "high level trigger" input - is that correct? And the output from the sensor which you want to connect to that relay module, goes "low" when you want to trigger the relay - is that correct? Please edit the question & add links to your specific relay module and sensor. Best would be proper datasheets, but I suspect these will be Amazon-type modules. Any links are better than none. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add links to the actual manufacturer's datasheets for the relay module and the sensor, not the the Amazon pages.

Comment: All I've got is this! I'm sorry but these are Chinese products from their oem markets hence mostly they won't be having any!

Comment: As we frequently say here, "no datasheet, no sale". You really should look for datasheets before you buy things.